# How can I get an specific value in a webpage?

Tags: python, windows, urllib

I have some `<div>`s and other stuff in a site and the specific line in the middle of inumerous divs

```
<input name="extWarrantyProds" type="hidden" value="23814298 ^ true"/>
```

How can I get the "value" part from this code, which it is in the middle of a site with other stuff ?

I'm trying with urllib but I don't even know where to start =/

Comment: [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/)

Comment: Do you have any control over the contents of the page? Can you reasonably guarantee it will not change too drastically? If yes, then simple pattern matching works (see below answers), otherwise you need to do "real" html parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of:

```
import urllib

urlStr = "http://www..."

fileObj = urllib.urlopen(urlStr)

for line in fileObj:
    if ('<input name="extWarrantyProds"' in line):
        startIndex = line.find('value="') + 7
        endIndex = line.find('"',startIndex)
        print line[startIndex:endIndex]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import lxml.html as lh

html = '''
<input name="extWarrantyProds" type="hidden" value="23814298 ^ true"/>
'''

# If you want to parse from a URL:
# tree = lh.parse('http://example.com')

tree = lh.fromstring(html)

print tree.xpath("//input[@name='extWarrantyProds']/@value")
```

Comment: regex + html = nightmares. +1 for using a proper parser. I'd also recommend looking at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ if you're planning on making a habit of this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

No need for anything too fancy if that's all you need. Download the page using `urllib` and look for the value using `re.findall()`.

```
import re
import urllib

url = 'http://...'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
matches = re.findall('<input name="extWarrantyProds.*?>', x, re.DOTALL)
for i in matches:
  print re.findall('value="(.*?)"', i)
```